# How to read json file and make data frame from different objects like Account and Inquiry etc in pandas

Tags: python, json, dataframe, json-normalize, pandas-explode

How to read json file and to make data frame with multiple objects like df in accounts df in enquiry df in address etc and Desired output like

df in accounts=Loansid,Applicationid,ReportingMemberShortName,AccountType,OwenershipIndicator,DateOpenedOrDisbursed,DateReportedAndCertified,HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount,CurrentBalance,PaymentHistory1,PaymentHistory2,PaymentHistoryStartDate,PaymentHistoryEndDate,ValueOfCollateral,TypeOfCollateral,RateOfInterest,RepaymentTenure,EmiAmount,PaymentFrequency

Python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('FILE.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'loans')

# get loanId
print(df['loanId'].values)

# get TransactionStatus
print(df['TransactionStatus.ResponseCode'].values)
print(df['TransactionStatus.ResponseMessage'].values)

# get AccountType
print(df['DCResponse.ContextData.Applicants.Applicant.DsCibilBureau.Response.CibilBureauResponse.BureauResponseXml.SucessResponse.Account'].values[0][0]['Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields'][0]['AccountType'])
```

```
{
  "loans": [
    {
      "loanId": "11111111111111111",
      "TransactionStatus": {
        "ResponseCode": "0",
        "ResponseMessage": "Success",
        "ExtendedErrorDetails": {
          "messages": {
            "code": "0",
            "message": "Success"
          }
        }
      },
      "DCResponse": {
        "Status": "Success",
        "Authentication": {
          "Status": "Success",
          "Token": "222222222222222222222222222222222"
        },
        "ResponseInfo": {
          "ApplicationId": "123456789",
          "SolutionSetInstanceId": "3333333333333333333333333333338"
        },
        "ContextData": {
          "Applicants": {
            "Applicant": {
              "Accounts": {
                "Account": null
              },
              "Addresses": {
                "Address": [
                  {
                    "StateCode": "23",
                    "PinCode": "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "City": "xxxx",
                    "AddressType": "02",
                    "AddressLine3": "xx",
                    "AddressLine2": "xxx",
                    "AddressLine1": "xxxx"
                  },
                  null
                ]
              },
              "Telephones": {
                "Telephone": [
                  {
                    "TelephoneType": "01",
                    "TelephoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx"
                  },
                  {
                    "TelephoneType": "02"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "Identifiers": {
                "Identifier": [
                  {
                    "IdType": "01",
                    "IdNumber": "xxxxxxxx"
                  },
                  {
                    "IdType": "02"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "EmailAddress": "xxxxxxxxx",
              "Gender": "Male",
              "DateOfBirth": "000000000",
              "ApplicantLastName": "xxxxx",
              "ApplicantFirstName": "xxxxxx",
              "ApplicantType": "xxxxxxxx",
              "NodeIdentifier": "0",
              "DsCibilBureau": {
                "DsCibilBureauData": {
                  "Request": {
                    "Request": {
                      "ConsumerDetails": {
                        "CreditReportInquiry": {
                          "Header": {
                            "SegmentTag": " TUEF ",
                            "Version": " 12 ",
                            "ReferenceNumber": "234444444444",
                            "MemberCode": "333333333333333333",
                            "Password": null,
                            "Purpose": "05",
                            "Amount": "100",
                            "ScoreType": "08",
                            "OutputFormat": "01",
                            "ResponseSize": "1",
                            "MediaType": "CC",
                            "AuthenticationMethod": "L"
                          },
                          "Names": {
                            "Name": {
                              "ConsumerName1": "xxxxx",
                              "ConsumerName3": "xxxxxx",
                              "DateOfBirth": "000000000",
                              "Gender": "xxxxxx"
                            }
                          },
                          "Identifications": {
                            "Identification": {
                              "PanNo": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                              "PassportNumber": null,
                              "DLNo": null,
                              "VoterId": null,
                              "UId": null,
                              "RationCardNo": null,
                              "AdditionalID1": null,
                              "AdditionalID2": null
                            }
                          },
                          "Telephones": {
                            "Telephone": {
                              "TelephoneNumber": "xxxxxxxxxx",
                              "TelephoneExtension": null,
                              "TelephoneType": "01"
                            }
                          },
                          "Addresses": {
                            "Address": {
                              "AddressLine1": "xxxxxxxx",
                              "AddressLine2": "d,,xxxxx",
                              "AddressLine3": "Default",
                              "AddressLine4": null,
                              "AddressLine5": "xxxxxx",
                              "StateCode": "23",
                              "PinCode": "1111111",
                              "AddressCategory": "02",
                              "ResidenceCode": null
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "DsCibilBureauStatus": null,
                "Response": {
                  "CibilBureauResponse": {
                    "BureauResponseRaw": "xxxxxxxxxx**",
                    "BureauResponseXml": {
                      "FailureResponse": null,
                      "SucessResponse": {
                        "Header": [
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "TUEF",
                            "Version": "12",
                            "ReferenceNumber": "353867102",
                            "MemberCode": "333333333333333333",
                            "SubjectReturnCode": "1",
                            "EnquiryControlNumber": "dddddddddddd",
                            "DateProcessed": "01032023",
                            "TimeProcessed": "022959"
                          }
                        ],
                        "NameSegment": [
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "N01",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "ConsumerName1FieldLength": "05",
                            "ConsumerName1": "xxxx",
                            "ConsumerName2FieldLength": "06",
                            "ConsumerName2": "xxxxx",
                            "DateOfBirthFieldLength": "08",
                            "DateOfBirth": "00000000",
                            "GenderFieldLength": "01",
                            "Gender": "2"
                          }
                        ],
                        "IDSegment": [
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "I01",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "IDType": "01",
                            "IDNumberFieldLength": "10",
                            "IDNumber": "xxxxxxx"
                          }
                        ],
                        "TelephoneSegment": [
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "T01",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "TelephoneNumberFieldLength": "10",
                            "TelephoneNumber": "000000000000",
                            "TelephoneType": "01"
                          },
                          {
                            "SegmentTag": "T02",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "TelephoneNumberFieldLength": "10",
                            "TelephoneNumber": "0000000000",
                            "TelephoneType": "01"
                          }
                        ],
                        "ScoreSegment": [
                          {
                            "Length": "10",
                            "ScoreName": "CIBILTUSC3",
                            "ScoreCardName": "08",
                            "ScoreCardVersion": "10",
                            "ScoreDate": "01032023",
                            "Score": "00719",
                            "ReasonCode1FieldLength": "02",
                            "ReasonCode1": "27",
                            "ReasonCode2FieldLength": "02",
                            "ReasonCode2": "25",
                            "ReasonCode3FieldLength": "02",
                            "ReasonCode3": "28",
                            "ReasonCode4FieldLength": "02",
                            "ReasonCode4": "15",
                            "ReasonCode5FieldLength": null,
                            "ReasonCode5": null
                          }
                        ],
                        "Address": [
                          {
                            "AddressSegmentTag": "PA",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "AddressLine1FieldLength": "18",
                            "AddressLine1": "xxxxx",
                            "AddressLine2FieldLength": "18",
                            "AddressLine2": "xxxxxxxxR",
                            "StateCode": "23",
                            "PinCodeFieldLength": "06",
                            "PinCode": "452001",
                            "AddressCategory": "02",
                            "DateReported": "31052022"
                          },
                          {
                            "AddressSegmentTag": "PA",
                            "Length": "03",
                            "AddressLine1FieldLength": "40",
                            "AddressLine1": "xxxxxxx",
                            "AddressLine2FieldLength": "23",
                            "AddressLine2": "xxxxxxxE",
                            "StateCode": "23",
                            "PinCodeFieldLength": "06",
                            "PinCode": "452009",
                            "AddressCategory": "02",
                            "DateReported": "19042019"
                          }
                        ],
                        "Account": [
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "T001",
                            "Account_Summary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13"
                              }
                            ],
                            "Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                                "ReportingMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                                "AccountType": "02",
                                "OwenershipIndicator": "4",
                                "DateOpenedOrDisbursed": "30012023",
                                "DateReportedAndCertified": "31012023",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength": "07",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount": "1500000",
                                "CurrentBalanceFieldLength": "07",
                                "CurrentBalance": "1200565",
                                "PaymentHistory1FieldLength": "03",
                                "PaymentHistory1": "STD",
                                "PaymentHistoryStartDate": "01012023",
                                "PaymentHistoryEndDate": "01012023",
                                "ValueOfCollateralFieldLength": "07",
                                "ValueOfCollateral": "3850000",
                                "TypeOfCollateralFieldLength": "02",
                                "TypeOfCollateral": "01",
                                "RateOfInterestFieldLength": "04",
                                "RateOfInterest": "9.00",
                                "RepaymentTenureFieldLength": "03",
                                "RepaymentTenure": "106",
                                "EmiAmountFieldLength": "05",
                                "EmiAmount": "16199",
                                "PaymentFrequency": "03"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "T002",
                            "Account_Summary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13"
                              }
                            ],
                            "Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                                "ReportingMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                                "AccountType": "00",
                                "OwenershipIndicator": "4",
                                "DateOpenedOrDisbursed": "30012023",
                                "DateReportedAndCertified": "30012023",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength": "07",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount": "1500000",
                                "CurrentBalanceFieldLength": "07",
                                "CurrentBalance": "1200000",
                                "PaymentHistory1FieldLength": "03",
                                "PaymentHistory1": "STD",
                                "PaymentHistoryStartDate": "01012023",
                                "PaymentHistoryEndDate": "01012023",
                                "ValueOfCollateralFieldLength": "07",
                                "ValueOfCollateral": "3850000",
                                "TypeOfCollateralFieldLength": "02",
                                "TypeOfCollateral": "01",
                                "RateOfInterestFieldLength": "04",
                                "RateOfInterest": "9.00",
                                "RepaymentTenureFieldLength": "03",
                                "RepaymentTenure": "106",
                                "EmiAmountFieldLength": "05",
                                "EmiAmount": "20249",
                                "PaymentFrequency": "03"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "T003",
                            "Account_Summary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13"
                              }
                            ],
                            "Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                                "ReportingMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                                "AccountType": "12",
                                "OwenershipIndicator": "1",
                                "DateOpenedOrDisbursed": "30052022",
                                "DateOfLastPayment": "30052022",
                                "DateReportedAndCertified": "30062022",
                                "CurrentBalanceFieldLength": "01",
                                "CurrentBalance": "0",
                                "PaymentHistory1FieldLength": "06",
                                "PaymentHistory1": "000000",
                                "PaymentHistoryStartDate": "01062022",
                                "PaymentHistoryEndDate": "01052022"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "T004",
                            "Account_Summary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13"
                              }
                            ],
                            "Account_NonSummary_Segment_Fields": [
                              {
                                "ReportingMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                                "ReportingMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                                "AccountType": "00",
                                "OwenershipIndicator": "1",
                                "DateOpenedOrDisbursed": "27042022",
                                "DateOfLastPayment": "02012023",
                                "DateReportedAndCertified": "31012023",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmountFieldLength": "04",
                                "HighCreditOrSanctionedAmount": "4000",
                                "CurrentBalanceFieldLength": "01",
                                "CurrentBalance": "0",
                                "PaymentHistory1FieldLength": "30",
                                "PaymentHistory1": "000000000000000000000000000000",
                                "PaymentHistoryStartDate": "01012023",
                                "PaymentHistoryEndDate": "01042022"
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ],
                        "Enquiry": [
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I001",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "21012023",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "02",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "07",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1500000"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I002",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "14122022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "06",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "AU SFB",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "10",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "03",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "100"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I003",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "03122022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "02",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "01",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I004",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "16112022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "02",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "06",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "500000"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I005",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "16112022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "02",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "06",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "500000"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I006",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "13082022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "00",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "01",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I007",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "17062022",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "00",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "01",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I008",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "31122021",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "06",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "05",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "13990"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I009",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "13122020",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "10",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "04",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "1000"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I010",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "10122020",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "05",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "03",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "100"
                          },
                          {
                            "Length": "04",
                            "SegmentTag": "I011",
                            "DateOfEnquiryFields": "19042019",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortNameFieldLength": "13",
                            "EnquiringMemberShortName": "NOT DISCLOSED",
                            "EnquiryPurpose": "06",
                            "EnquiryAmountFieldLength": "05",
                            "EnquiryAmount": "40990"
                          }
                        ],
                        "End": [
                          {
                            "TotalLength": "0001735",
                            "SegmentTag": "ES07"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "ApplicationData": {
            "FormattedReport": true,
            "ConsumerConsentForUIDAIAuthentication": "N",
            "NTCProductType": "PL",
            "MFIBureauFlag": "True",
            "IDVerificationFlag": "False",
            "DSTuNtcFlag": "True",
            "CibilBureauFlag": "False",
            "Password": null,
            "MemberCode": "NB66529999_CIRC2CNPE",
            "GSTStateCode": "08",
            "ScoreType": "08",
            "Amount": "100",
            "Purpose": "05",
            "MFIDocRequest": "\n",
            "ReturnMessage": "\n",
            "DTTrail": {
              "Step": {
                "Name": "\n",
                "Duration": "\n"
              }
            },
            "Milestone": {
              "Step": "\n"
            },
            "Start": "\n",
            "InputValReasonCodes": "\n",
            "User": "NB6652DC01_PROD001",
            "BusinessUnitId": "23",
            "ApplicationId": "353867102",
            "SolutionSetId": "50",
            "EnvironmentTypeId": "2",
            "EnvironmentType": "Production"
          },
          "Decision": null,
          "ApplicationId": null
        }
      },
      "FileContent": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=="
    }
  ]
}
```